# What is the fastest way to store unknown amount of strings in java?

Tags: java, list, collections

I want to store an unknown amount of strings and later read them in the order they were added. As I said the only features I need are:

- Possibility to add an unknown amount of strings without slowing down because of resizing
- Possibility to read the elements in the order they were added

The problem is that I want to output strings from part of a trie. So counting the strings before returning them would double the amount of time needed for the operation.

(Another solution would be to keep track of the number of strings in the trie using an attribute but as I want to return just a part of the trie this isn't a perfect solution either)

Comment: What options have you considered?

Comment: How many (order of magnitude) strings are, on average, expected? Is the number known at runtime before reading? Are we talking about a hard real time application or are you simply optimizing prematurely? I can give you vastly different answers (well, educated guesses) depending on the answer to each of these questions, and there are likely more factors. Besides, the only univeral answer to "which is faster?" is "try it out and profile!".

Comment: @delnan After some testing it seems like ArrayList is faster. If there are that different possibilities you could tell me when each of them is faster.

Comment: As my comment to Jon Skeet's answer indicates: If you can get away without resizing, array-based solutions are faster to allocate and manipulate; otherwise various linked lists (depending on what kind of operations you need) can be useful; unrolling these lists (grouping several items into one list node, avoiding allocations and pointer chasing) may also be useful if there's a large number of items. If you need particular access patterns, queues or dequeues may be an option. And lastly, if you're just optimizing prematurely, the overall most optimal choice is whatever is readily available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An ArrayList is generally faster than a LinkedList. If you don't specify an appropriate size, each time the capacity is exhausted, it will have to reassign a new array (with the double size) and copy the elements to a new array, though.

You could use a LinkedList to avoid this cost, but the average time will probably be bigger.

Whatever the collection you use, if you don't have enough memory, the GC will trigger, which could also introduce some delay. An "unknown amount", without any limit, is impossible to store in any in-memory collection. If "unknown" can be very very large and forbid the usage of an in-memory collection, you'll have to us a file or a database.

Answer (score 7):

[`LinkedList<string>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) sounds like a good bet to me...

- Maintains order
- O(1) addition at head or tail
- O(1) removal at head or tail
- Cheap iteration

It's expensive to get at an arbitrary element, which is the normal reason not to use it... but it sounds like that isn't a problem in your case.

Comment: Of course, complexity isn't everything. Assume, for the sake of the argument, OP seriously needs the fastest (as in miliseconds) approach for N-M strings. If the actual number is known before the first string is read, arrays needn't be resized and are a single allocation. Similarily, if M is reasonably small, one can probably avoid re-allocations by just going for worst-case size. There are probably more exceptions. I'm not saying anything against your answer, or any other answer, only against this kind of question ("I need to do X; I don't know Y and Z but I really need to make it fast!").

Comment: [LinkedList is much slower than ArrayList](http://ideone.com/Uq7oc) for basic operations. `LinkedList` creates new object for every element, which turns out to be more work than what `ArrayList` is doing.

Comment: While `LinkedList` probably exhibits a more stable add time, the overall performance of `LinkedList` for inserting many elements seems to be slightly worse than `ArrayList`. (See my answer for some benchmark results.) `LinkedList` is also slightly slower to iterate (using an iterator -- it would be much slower to iterate using explicit indexing); following references isn't as fast as indexing into an array.

Answer (score 2):

The two obvious choices are `ArrayList` and `LinkedList`. A `LinkedList` appears to be slightly slower than `ArrayList`. Here's my benchmarking code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class ListTest {
    private static final int N = 50000;
    private static final float NANO_TO_MILLI = 1.0e-6f;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] strings = new String[N];
        for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
            strings[i] = Integer.toString(i);
        }

        System.out.print("ArrayList: ");
        benchmark(strings, new ArrayList<String>());

        System.out.print("LinkedList: ");
        benchmark(strings, new LinkedList<String>());
    }

    private static void benchmark(String[] strings, List<String> list) {
        // measure how long it takes to add the strings
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        for (String s : strings) {
            list.add(s);
        }
        long addTime = System.nanoTime() - start;

        // measure how long it takes to iterate the list
        start = System.nanoTime();
        int i = 0;
        for (String s : list) {
            ++i;
        }
        long iterateTime = System.nanoTime() - start;

        // report the results
        System.out.println(String.format("add: %.2fms; iterate: %.2fms (%d strings)",
            addTime * NANO_TO_MILLI,
            iterateTime * NANO_TO_MILLI,
            i));
    }
}
```

And here are the results of a typical run:

> ArrayList: add: 5.52ms; iterate: 7.66ms (50000 strings)
>   LinkedList: add: 7.79ms; iterate: 8.32ms (50000 strings)

This was on a Windows machine with an Intel Core2 Quad Q6600 2.4GHz cpu.

Note that this only measures the overall time. It doesn't measure the variation in add time of individual strings, which I would expect to be higher for `ArrayList` than for `LinkedList`, due to the need to reallocate the internal array.

EDIT: If I modify `main` to repeat the test five times in a row, with a call to `System.gc()` after each call to `benchmark`, then I get some interesting results:

> ArrayList: add: 5.84ms; iterate: 7.84ms (50000 strings)
>   LinkedList: add: 7.24ms; iterate: 8.27ms (50000 strings)
>
> ArrayList: add: 0.45ms; iterate: 0.60ms (50000 strings)
>   LinkedList: add: 0.84ms; iterate: 5.35ms (50000 strings)
>
> ArrayList: add: 0.52ms; iterate: 0.72ms (50000 strings)
>   LinkedList: add: 0.81ms; iterate: 5.57ms (50000 strings)
>
> ArrayList: add: 3.77ms; iterate: 0.71ms (50000 strings)
>   LinkedList: add: 3.35ms; iterate: 0.93ms (50000 strings)
>
> ArrayList: add: 3.39ms; iterate: 0.87ms (50000 strings)
>   LinkedList: add: 3.38ms; iterate: 0.86ms (50000 strings)

This is probably due to caching by the cpu. Note that `LinkedList` can be slightly faster (e.g., the last to iterations) for adding strings, although it can also be much slower. Iteration can also be drastically slower for `LinkedList`, also probably because of lack of locality.

Comment: Thanks for your post. Currently I'm using ArrayList, so I'm going to stay with that.

Answer (score 1):

Use an implementation of the `List` interface. It's [generally](http://chaoticjava.com/posts/linkedlist-vs-arraylist/) [considered](http://www.narendranaidu.com/2006/09/arraylist-vs-linkedlist.html) that `ArrayList` is the best general-purpose collection to use, so do something as simple as this for storing your strings:

```
List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>();
```